# Manually trigger DAG from UI. Task status is set to None in Airflow and not making progress

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

**Airflow version 1.10.10**

All that am trying to do is write a test DAG and trigger it from Airflow UI manually. When the DAG is manually triggered from Airflow UI, task status is set to None and not making any progress.

Here is the configuration

```
{
  'owner': 'etladmin',
  'depends_on_past': False,
  'start_date': <Pendulum [2019-09-29T23:59:00+00:00]>,
  'email': ['user@org.com'],
  'email_on_failure': True,
  'email_on_retry': True
}
```

Here is the sample code

```
from airflow.contrib.hooks.ssh_hook import SSHHook
from airflow.contrib.operators.ssh_operator import SSHOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.models import DAG, Variable

default_args = {
    'owner': 'etladmin',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 9, 29, 23, 59),
    'email': ['user@org.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True
}

dag = DAG('sample_run',
          default_args=default_args,
          max_active_runs=1,
          catchup=False,
          dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=40),
          schedule_interval=None
        )

bash_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_date',
    bash_command='date',
    dag=dag
)

# Run tasks
bash_task
```

Related logs

```
[2022-04-17 14:05:02,444] {{scheduler_job.py:154}} INFO - Started process (PID=16534) to work on /app/airflow/dags/sample_run.py
[2022-04-17 14:05:02,446] {{scheduler_job.py:1562}} INFO - Processing file /app/airflow/dags/sample_run.py for tasks to queue
[2022-04-17 14:05:02,446] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2022-04-17 14:05:02,446] {{dagbag.py:396}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /app/airflow/dags/sample_run.py
[2022-04-17 14:05:02,580] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2022-04-17 14:05:02,581] {{scheduler_job.py:1574}} INFO - DAG(s) dict_keys(['sample_run']) retrieved from /app/airflow/dags/sample_run.py
[2022-04-17 14:05:02,594] {{scheduler_job.py:162}} INFO - Processing /app/airflow/dags/sample_run.py took 0.150 seconds
```

From the logs, could not figure out anything related to incorrect/invalid start_date value. start_date value is not dynamic and not in the future. Please note that schedule_interval is set to **None** explicitly. Since its a test job, every time it would be triggered from UI only.

From the below image, there are 4 instances of the run and all of them get into None status.

[image]

Any pointers on where I am missing?

Comment: Why are you trying to pass owner/start_date/etc via the Trigger DAG? this is not what this is for.

Comment: @EladKalif Have seen other code with owner, start_date in the default_args which is then used in constructing DAG, so am not sure if this is the reason.

Comment: ah now I understand what you mean but I don't understand what is the issue you are experiencing. I'm not able to reproduce. Your DAG runs just fine

Comment: @EladKalif Edited question and added image snapshot that describes more about the problem.

Comment: Airflow 1.10.10 went out of support a long time ago, I'd recommend you start using Airflow 2 versions. Plus, you'll get a lot of new features